# Hibernate/GORM: collection was not processed by flush()

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an integration test in my Grails application that fails when I try to save an entity of type `Member`

```
invitingMember.save(flush: true)
```

This raises the following exception

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure:
>   collection
>   [com.mycompany.facet.Facet.channels] was
>   not processed by flush() at
>   com.mycompany.member.MemberConnectionService.addOrUpdateContact(MemberConnectionService.groovy:939)

Earlier in the transaction I add an object to a collection property of `invitingMember`. My guess is that the exception is thrown at the line above, because it's only at this point that the object added to the collection is persisted.

Answer (score 9):

The underlying problem is probably that Hibernate doesn't cascade the save. So when you flush the `Member`, Hibernate notices that the collection is still dirty (which is probably not what you want). So either flush the collection manually or [tell Hibernate to cascade all the updates](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that when using GORM (the ORM used by Grails that is built "on top of" Hibernate) saves are cascaded by default.

Answer (score 5):

I found a possible solution [here](http://blog.holyjeez.com/2010/01/20/hibernate-flush-problem-orghibernateassertionfailure-collection-was-not-processed-by-flush/).

Actually, look at toString, equals, hashcode and make sure you are not accessing your lazy accessor.

I know I am talking about java and here the question is about grails but maybe there is the same kind of thing for grails.

Don't hesitate to edit.

It was the issue for me (in java)

Answer (score 2):

The only time I've encountered that exeception is when using Hibernate events e.g. beforeInsert, beforeUpdate etc - are you using these?

There's an issue in JIRA related to this which has been fixed for Grails 1.2

Answer (score 2):

I had that error when a tried to add element to a collection after delete elements from the collection. I solved it by calling `save(flush:true)` before add new elements to the collection.

- In my case, the collection is always returned from a `select`.