# Grails Error log.info fix my code

Tags: grails, logging, groovy

my Error is very crazy. I want to debug my error. 
Insert log.info $game and the error was gone.

Code:

```
private void calcAndUpdateStatEntriesOfOutOfOrderGame(Game game, Team team) {
    Competition competition = game.round.competition
    Round currentRound = competition.currentRound


    // if game of team has been played in current round -> update stats of current round
    // if not => update previous round
    Round statsRound
    if (game.state > Game.STATE_NOT_STARTED) {
        statsRound = currentRound       // the stats of the game are saved to the current round of the competition              
    } else {
        // the home team did not yet play yet at the current round -> save the stats at the previous round, otherwise it will be overwritten when the game is played                    
        statsRound = currentRound.previousRound
    }

    CompetitionTableEntry compTableEntry = CompetitionTableEntry.getByRoundAndTeam(statsRound, team)    // get the stats for home team / round of game      
    if (!compTableEntry) {
        // looks like there are no stats created for this round yet => create them
        createCompetitionRankingEntries(statsRound, false)
        compTableEntry = CompetitionTableEntry.getByRoundAndTeam(statsRound, team)
    }

    def stats = getStatisticsForTeamUntilGame(competition, game, team)
    compTableEntry.properties = stats
    compTableEntry.save()
}
```

Error:

```
Error 500: Executing action [updateResult] of controller [at.ligaportal.GameController] caused exception: collection [at.ligaportal.Team.staffMembers] was not processed by flush()
Servlet: grails
URI: /ligaportal/grails/game/updateResult.dispatch
Exception Message: collection [at.ligaportal.Team.staffMembers] was not processed by flush() 
Caused by: collection [at.ligaportal.Team.staffMembers] was not processed by flush() 
Class: ApiAuthenticationFilter 
At Line: [77] 
Code Snippet:
```

When i add after `Round currentRound = competition.currentRound` the line

```
log.info "$game"
```

the Error is gone, and it all works fine.
But this is for my no fix...

Where is my real problem?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701600/hibernate-gorm-collection-was-not-processed-by-flush

Comment: Does your `Game` class have a custom `toString()`?  If so this may be touching some other properties of the object and causing Hibernate to initialize some lazy proxy or other that would not otherwise have been initialized.