# Error Flushing Roles

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.2.5 and Spring Security 1.2.7.3 and am getting

```
collection SecUser.roles was not processed by flush()
```

It's happening when I'm not even accessing a user or the roles collection, specifically when I'm using a dynamic finder method from GORM.  Is there some domain configuration or spring security configuration that could be causing this?

Comment: you can see here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701600/hibernate-gorm-collection-was-not-processed-by-flush

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue was related to GORM triggers onUpdate() onCreate() . I had those triggers adding the createdBy and updatedBy user. As soon as I took out that code, I received no more errors.

Also received the error another place in my application and added a User.withNewSession{...} closure which also suppressed the error. Still not entirely sure of the root cause.